# IIS6 windows authentication only working when site is accessed by DNS name (not IP address)

Tags: windows, iis, authentication, iis-6

In IIS 6, I have a web site where anonymous authentication is turned off, so that only my domain users can access the site, and so IIS will recognize the user (if they access the site on a computer that's joined to the domain, and they're logged into the domain).

This works fine if the site is browsed by name (server name or localhost).  But if the site is browsed by an IP address or an FQDN, the IIS server doesn't recognize the user's computer, and it prompts for authentication.

Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with "zones" - you need to add your [fqdn to intranet zone](https://serverfault.com/q/51187). IE recognizes patterns in the url you type (and determines what zone they belong to).

Comment: Exactly right.  Thank you.  For posterity, this described my symptoms exactly: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/domains2/preventing-iis-from-prompting-for-user-credentials